# how to source an R project that includes here::here() links with another R project that also includes here::here() links

Tags: r

I have an R studio project with a main.R (see sample code) file that sources a few other scripts within this project using `here::here()`, and also uses `here()` within the scripts its sourcing. This first R studio project produces a dataset that I would to use in another R studio project also using `here()` with a similar structure in terms of the main.R script.

**First project**

```
library(here)

here::here()

#1. load packages
source(paste0(here::here(),"/R/load_packages.R"))

#2. load UDF functions

source(paste0(here::here(),"/R/functions.R"))

#3. Load BA data

source(paste0(here::here(),"/analysis/load_ba.R"))

#4. Load CDS data

source(paste0(here::here(),"/analysis/load_cds.R"))

#5. Calculate

source(paste0(here::here(),"/analysis/calculate.R"))
```

**Second project**

```
library(here)
here::here()
#load packages
source(base::paste0(here::here(),"/analysis/packages.R"))

#load and manipulate pop/ds data
source("first project full file path/main.R")
```

So my question is, what is the best way to source the first main.R file that produces the data set I want to use in the second R studio project without the `here()` links breaking?

One option is to write the output dataset to csv and then read it in, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: When you say "R Project" do you mean "RStudio Project" or simply a folder with some R code and data etc in? Because there's no "project" in R, its an RStudio thing only.

Answer (score 0):

The Right Way to do this is to build any code you want to re-use as a package that exports functions (and maybe fixed datasets) for other code to re-use.

I can think of hacky ways to do what you want, most of them rely on passing a folder from the calling code in a global variable or changing the current folder to the called code using `setwd` (or `withr::with_dir`) but these are messy. Make packages and create functions instead.

You might be tempted by the `whereami` package and its `thisfile` function. But read the help - even the authors don't want you to use it:

```
 *CAVEAT*: Use this function only if your
     workflow does not permit other solution: if a script needs to know
     its location, it should be set outside the context of the script
     if possible.
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code i want to re use connects to an ODBC database and imports some other excel files. The database is quite large too so it takes 5-ish minutes to produce the output dataset so turning it into a package doesnt seem like the best option in this case

Comment: What? The package would do exactly what "source" on the file would do but only when you call a function from the package. eg library(mydatabasething); data = getmydatabase("name of database")` or something like that. The time taken, size of database etc aren't relevant.